# Error: Cannot find module 'material-ui/Grid'

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm making a ReactJS project and I have no problems with any of the material-ui components except Grid and Radio button.

They give me the error

```
Error: Cannot find module 'material-ui/Grid'
```

Why most components can be found but these two don't?

Comment: Grid is only available on the beta version. If you have any version below `1.x`, then there is no `Grid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open your package.json and double check that you are running the version 1.x of material-ui. If you are running 0.x branch, try installing with the following:

`npm install material-ui@next`

Comment: Did that. Now it can't find Toggle. Which was in 0.0.20. :)